# Run multiple jar files from intellij idea and change, run and debug through.

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, jar, remote-debugging, intellij-14

So I basically want to debug through multiple jar files all different microservices that send/receive messages to/from each other's APIs. What I do at the moment is to run each jar files from my command line as java -jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 ***.jar and do a remote debugging with my intellij with the same port.

I was wondering whether it is possible to have all jar files into one configuration and start them all in one debugging session in Intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Are the micro services runnable on a webserver like Tomcat?  If so, you can download the webserver, add it to IntelliJ and deploy these three micro services in the same run configuration.  You should then be able to debug that run configuration and debug these at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your post. That's the problem. They are not in a webserver like Tomcat. I have used that approach with other projects and it very much made sense to me.

Comment: I obviously know nothing of your environment, but it seems like a true micro service should run on a web server.  How will these services be consumed in production? If you're using Maven or Gradle it would be simple to change to a war and deploy the code.

Comment: True. All Jar files are build using Gradle but they are all running on different VM machines and are connected through APIs. I see your point that it is an option to make them all running on a web server (good option is to have an .ear file) but it would be so convenient if I could have the same sturcture and run them all at the same time.

Comment: You don't have to combine them into a single ear/dar when you deploy to production.  Depending on your load requirements you may not want to, that's up to you to figure out.  However, in IntelliJ you can deploy them at the same time using an application server.